# jQuery - looping through tables and getting widths and setting parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

long day so most likely me missing something silly but what i want to do is loop through the tables getting their widths and then setting the width on a parent element but not working any thoughts or see where ive gone wrong?

HTML

```
<div class="vScroll">

  <table class="table-scroll">
   ....
  </table>

  <div class="box-bottom">stuff here</div>

</div>

<div class="vScroll">

  <table class="table-scroll">
   ....
  </table>

  <div class="box-bottom">stuff here</div>

</div>

<div class="vScroll">

  <table class="table-scroll">
   ....
  </table>

  <div class="box-bottom">stuff here</div>

</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery('.vScroll .table-scroll').each(function(i,el) {
  var $tableSize = jQuery(this).width();
  jQuery(this).parent('.box-bottom').css('width',$tableSize);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: wher is .table-scroll ?

Comment: Should `table-class` be `table-scroll`?

Comment: sorry yes, my mistake

Comment: @JamesBrandon well, then *fix* the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
$('.vScroll .table-scroll').each(function(i,el) {
    var $tableSize = $(this).width();
    $('.box-bottom', $(this).parent()).css('width',$tableSize);
});
```

It seems like what you are getting from

```
var $tableSize = $(this).width();
```

is not exactly what you need. It will return the width of parent div containing the table. If you really want to select the table instead of the div, use

```
$('.table-scroll').each(function(i,el) {
```

Answer (score 0):

With a few minor alterations, I think I corrected your JS code and created what I believe is a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Xeb4S/2/

Essentially, this is the resulting JS

`$('.vScroll .table-class').each(function() {
  var $tableSize = $(this).width();
  $(this).siblings('.box-bottom').css('width',$tableSize);
});`

There are a few alterations, mainly adding some body to the `table` HTML and giving the correct class name in the selector - but you also don't need to pass in the parameters to `.each()` if they're not being used and I shortened the jQuery references to just `$`

I also used `siblings` to set the width of the `.box-bottom` item directly underneath? It is a slight assumption. You mention "setting the width of a parent item" - but the `.box-bottom` items are siblings, not parents?

Hope this helps.